# Django ORM - understanding foreign key queries

Tags: sql, django, orm

I'm in a process of optimizing my queries. Assume I have these models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

A simple task here would be to get all the books of a given author, assume I have the author-ID.

In standard SQL I would only need to query the books table.

But In django code I do:

```
# given authorID
author = Author.objects.get(pk=authorID)
books = Book.objects.filter(author=author)
```

Which would take two queries. How can I avoid the first query ?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
Book.objects.filter(author_id=authorID)
```

This will return all the books where author's foreign key is authorID.

Comment: and what if I want to create a new book in one query? I mean: Book.objects.create(name="name", author=.. )